# Jquery Drag and Drop with sortable Unexpexted behaviour

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

I am trying to make a drag and drop with sortable . I have Two panel left and right .In left panel I have some drag element which can be clone or without clone.
I have to drop left panel element in right panel .In this case we can sort trash element. In my case Drag drop and sortable working fine but some time it shows different behavior please refer attached images. [Live Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s5pxcepa/9/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var new_id = 20;
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var $gallery = $(".gallery");
        $("li", $gallery).draggable({
            cursor: 'move',
            revert: 'invalid',
            containment: "#area",
            helper: function () {
                //alert($(this).attr('class'));
                var cloned = $(this).clone();
                cloned.attr('id', (++new_id).toString());
                return cloned;
            },
            distance: 20
        });

        $("#trash").droppable({
            tolerance: 'pointer',
            items: "li:not(.editable)",
            accept: function (event, ui) {
                return true;
            },
            drop: function (event, ui) {
                var id = ui.draggable[0].id;
                var color = $(ui.draggable).css("background-color");

                var obj;
                if ($(ui.helper).hasClass('draggable')) {
                    obj = SetDropElementStyle($(ui.helper).clone(), color);
                    $(this).append(obj);
                }

            }
        }).sortable({
            revert: false,
            items: "li:not(.editable)",
            containment: "#trash",
            opacity: 0.6
        });

    });

function SetDropElementStyle(_obj, _color) {
        var imgtype = "";

        var itemWidth = 50;
        if ((_color == "rgb(70, 130, 180)") || (_color == "#4682B4")) {
            $(_obj).find('img').remove();
            var TypeID = $(_obj).attr('typeid');
            imgtype = "R";
            _obj.removeClass('draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging recipintlist').addClass('flowIn').removeAttr('style');
            if ($.trim(_obj[0].innerText).length > 0) {
                itemWidth = ($.trim(_obj[0].innerText).length + 1) * 10;
            }
            $(_obj).css({ 'width': itemWidth });
            $("[typeid|='" + TypeID + "']").remove();
        }
        if ((_color == "rgb(237, 125, 49)") || (_color == "#ED7D31")) {
            var delayText = "+<span>0</span>h&nbsp;<span>01</span>mn"
            _obj.removeClass('draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging actionlistDelay').addClass('delay').removeAttr('style');
            imgtype = "D";
            _obj.append(delayText);
        }
        if ((_color == "rgb(186, 56, 56)") || (_color == "#ba3838")) {
            $(_obj).find('span').remove();
            var haltText = "<div style='width:1px;color:white;'>H<br/>A<br/>L<br/>T</div>";
            _obj.removeClass('draggable ui-draggable ui-draggable-dragging actionlistHalt').addClass('halt').removeAttr('style');
            imgtype = "H";
            _obj.append(haltText);
        }


        return _obj;
}
</script>
```